# Which variable type to use when sending an image to frontend? .NET EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need to send an image along with some other data to my front-end of a web application and am wondering which data type to use. I am using .NET EF Core 6 and React.js for this project.

I tried using Image, byte[], IFormFile, string version of the byte[] but couldn't manage to find a way to retrieve my saved picture in a way to send it to my front-end. Here is the code:

```
public class User : IEntity
    {
        //data containing string, int etc.
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    }
```

Part above is the object I am trying to send.

```
public IDataResult<User> Add(UserAddDTO userInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                var userAdd = new User
                {
                    //assigning variables
                    ProfilePicture = userInfo.ProfilePicture.FileName,
                };
                if (userInfo.ProfilePicture.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (FileStream filestream = File.Create(/*file location*/)
                    {
                        userInfo.ProfilePicture.CopyTo(filestream);
                        filestream.Flush();
                    }
                }
                _userDao.Add(userAdd);
                return new SuccessDataResult<User>(userAdd, Messages.UserAdded);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                return new ErrorDataResult<User>(Ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Part above is the business logic part. In this part variables and the picture is being received and the picture is saved into a file. In the database other variables and the name of the file is held.

Up to here there is no problem. What I also want to do is return this newly created User back in SuccessDataResult<User> object. How can I get my saved image in a way that allows me to send it along with other data?

Comment: you can load image from file after you retrieve user from database. so what you actually problem is ?

Comment: As I stated at the top of my question, I couldn't figure out which type of variable I need to hold this image in. So that when I get this image into a variation of User and send it, I can access and show this image in my front-end.

Comment: It depends. I suggest you put the file on the static folder, and the User entity include the file url, so your front-end can direct  access the the file. the other way is that you read the file and base64 it, then return the base64 string to front-end.   both method, the type of variable is string.

Comment: This solution was actually what I meant by using string version of byte[], so I actually tried that previously but now that I try it again I realize my problem was something entirely different than what I posted. I was trying to use received Base64String in an icon which is in a button object in my front-end which was apparently not possible. After changing the button object to hold an image object as a children it received the image. So reading the file and transforming it into Base64String works and answers my question. Thank you for the answers.